# Importing ts files in nestJs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm new to nestJs,

I have written one file called constants.ts

```
module.exports = {
    ROLES: {
        ADMIN: 'admin',
        LOCAL: 'local'
    }
}
```

This file I'm trying to import in another file with below code.

```
import * as constants from '../lib/constants'
```

But getting 'constants.ts' is not a module error.

Can anyone help me on this? Please.

And also please tell me how to import .json files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to import a CommonJS module in a TypeScript module, which can cause issues. To fix this, you can try changing the module exports in your 'constants.ts' file to a TypeScript module format:

```
export const ROLES = {
  ADMIN: 'admin',
  LOCAL: 'local'
};
```

And then in the file where you want to import it:

```
import { ROLES } from '../lib/constants';
```

Regarding importing JSON files, you can use the import statement as well. For example, if you have a file called config.json, you can import it like this:

```
import config from './config.json';
```

Keep in mind that if you're using TypeScript, you may need to define a type for the imported JSON data. You can do this by creating an interface for the JSON structure:

```
interface Config {
  apiUrl: string;
  apiKey: string;
}

const config: Config = require('./config.json');
```